# Installing several versions of a package

Tags: packages, installing

Sometimes it would be convenient to have several versions of a package installed at once. For example I’d like to have a development version of TikZ for my own work and the current stable version to test whether code I share works with it.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Edit: I’m using Linux and TL 2010.

Comment: Could you tell us which OS you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`, "You can set an environment variable to override TEXMF if you're testing a new TeX tree, without changing anything else."

If you don't want a full TeX tree, you can use the `TEXMFHOME` environment variable to point that at something other than `~/texmf`. For example,

```
export TEXMFHOME=~/texmf-testing
```

Then install the testing versions of packages in there.

Comment: Due to some unfathomable design decisions made back in its `MS-DOS` days, `export TEXMFHOME=~/texmf-testing` won't work on `Windows` systems.  If you're not running `Windows`, all well and good. If you are, then you'll either need to use symlinks or reset your `TEXMFHOME` in a new command shell then launch `latex` etc. from that new shell.

Comment: @Caramdir. Just noted you updated your question for Linux.  Although TH's answer involving `export` is clearly best for you, I'll leave my alternative (symlinks) answer stand for anyone interested in taking a `Windows` system path.

Comment: @Geoffry: I intended this question to be os neutral.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of right now is to have several local trees with different package versions in them. Then you could hook the trees in your distribution. In e.g. MikTeX it is fairly easy to change the order in which trees are searched. Just make sure that the package you want to use is in the first tree.

This is however by far not an automated process....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be hard to automate at all. Providing your environment exposes symlinks (`linux` and `windows` do, `mac` presumably as well), it should be pretty easy to set up a little script to switch various subtrees in and out. Include a call to `texhash` or whatever your distro gives you and you should be flying in no time at all. : )

Comment: Mac OS X has been a *nix OS for the better part of a decade. It has standard symlinks as well as classic Mac OS aliases.