# How do I temporarily change the PGF version used?

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing several versions of a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/installing-several-versions-of-a-package)

This might be a more general question but I'm interested in the PGF implementation so I'll ask specifically.  I have TikZ code that worked a few months ago but doesn't compile now and I suspect it's 2.10 bug.  What's the quickest way to test my code in PGF 2.0?

The way I did it the last and only time was I logged in as a different user and ran the same code.  The reason it worked is that I have PGF 2.0 installed in my `/usr/local/texlive` distribution but PGF 2.10 in my user `~/Library/texmf` directory.  Different user, different path, different package loaded.

But's a pain to logout or switch users.  Is there a simpler way to change this on the fly?  Symbolic links maybe?

Comment: See [Installing several versions of a package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/installing-several-versions-of-a-package).

Comment: D'oh! That does look like the same question.  Sorry my initial searches did not turn that up.

Comment: Matthew, does Caramdir's link answer your question?  You've currently got 2 votes to close-as-duplicate so if _not_ you should explain why not.  (Ooops, cross-posted with your comment; is it okay to close-as-duplicate?)

Comment: In theory it does, although I haven't tested.  If I concur with the vote to close should I just delete?

Comment: No, deleting and closing are very different! Since your searches did not lead you to that question, it would be better to have this question pointing to it...that way there is a higher probability that the next user finds one of these two questions!

Comment: @Matthew. On meta, the general feeling has been that we won't delete questions (I guess unless they are out-and-out spam). As Yossi says, marked-up dupes should help with searching.

Comment: Yossi is completely correct.  Given that you didn't find it, having the duplicate adds usability to the site.  (If, for some reason, Caramdir's link does _not_ answer your question, either edit this one and we'll reopen or ask a new question but be sure to explain what _didn't_ work in relation to that question.)